# How do I use padding for specifically this id and another id?

Tags: php, html, css

[Image of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjI1J.jpg)

Hi guys, so apparently I have issues with padding, I have been trying to pad the top big black arrow under the "Welcome, Motalvinl" instead of the table that contains "File, ..." Do you guys have any ways to do so? I'm actually currently under the padding of the table "File,..." I wish to just be padding below the "Welcome, Motalvinl". Of course, I do not want my table to be under the bottom arrow, I want it to still be in the middle of the webpage, I just want changes for my padding for the Big Black Arrow under the "Welcome, Motalvinl". Thank you guys for the help! Appreciated much!

These are my codes

```
<?php 
include_once 'db.php'; //Establishing connection with our database
include_once 'https.php';
include_once 'secure_session_start.php';


secure_session_start(); //Start session
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Popup box to confirm logout  -->
<script>
    function Confirmlogout()
    {
      var x = confirm("Are you sure you want log out?");
      if (x)
          return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
</script> 

<!-- Webpage information -->
    <title>Firewall Rule Review System</title>
    <meta name="author" content="your name" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css" type="text/css" />

<style>

<!-- Table format --> 

div.container{

    width:98%;
    margin:1%;
    overflow: auto;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:auto;
    z-index: 100;
    width:600px;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align:center; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    width:100px;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#fff;
}
table#t01 th {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Webpage Content-->
    <div id="page">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="#"><b>Firewall Rule Review System</b></a></h1>
            <h2><b><?php echo 'Welcome, '.$_SESSION['usern'];?></b></h2>
        </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="red"><a href="#/about.html"><b>About</b></a></li>
                <li class="orange"><a href="#/contact.html"><b>Contact</b></a></li>
                <li class="blue"><a href="logout.php" onclick="return Confirmlogout();"><b>Logout</b></a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>

        <html>
            <div class ="container">
                <table id="t01">
                <tr>
                    <th>File</th>
                    <th>Size</th> 
                    <th>Upload-DateTime</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </html>

        <div class="point-top"></div>

            <div class="triangles-menu">
                <a href="HOMEPAGE LINK HERE">Home</a>
                <a href="uploadfilepg.php" name="uploadfile"> Upload File</a>
                <a href="filerecords.php">File Records</a>
                <a href="LINK HERE">Change Password</a>
            </div>


        <div class="point-bottom"></div> </div>

    <!-- End Page Content -->
    <div class="footer">
    <p>
        Testing
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it will look like this
[Perfect Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq3y0.jpg)

Here are my Css!

```
/*
* multi-line comment
*/
p{ line-height: 1em; }
h1, h2, h3, h4{
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
}
h1{ font-size: 1.7em; }
h2{ font-size: 1.5em; }
a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: blink;
}
    a:hover,
    a:active{ text-decoration: blink; }

body{
    font-family: arial; font-size: 80%; line-height: 1.2em; width: 100%; margin: 0; background: #eee;
    font-weight: normal;
}
/* you can but your code all in one line like above */
#page{ margin: 20px; }

/* or on different lines like below */
#logo{
    width: 35%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: arial;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* but try and be as consist possible */
#nav{
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
    #nav ul{}
        #nav ul li{
            display: inline-block;
            height: 62px;
        }
            #nav ul li a{
                padding: 20px;
                background: red;
                color: #000000;
            }
            #nav ul li a:hover{
                background-color: #ff8000;
                box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #666;
            }
            #nav ul li a:active{ background-color: #ff8f00; }
                #nav ul li.red a{
                    background-color: red;
                }
                #nav ul li.orange a{
                    background-color: orange;
                }
                #nav ul li.blue a{
                    background-color: #0080ff;
                }

#content{
    margin: 30px 0;
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
#footer{
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
    #footer p{
        text-align: right;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 80%;
        color: grey;
    }

/* multiple styles seperated by a , */
#content,
ul li a{ box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999; }

/* User Login Page */

.point-top,
.point-bottom {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 75px solid transparent;
    border-left: 75px solid transparent;
}

.point-top {
  border-bottom: 50px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  padding-top: 2em; 
}

.point-bottom {
  border-top: 50px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.triangles-menu {
  background-color: #d5d2d5;
  width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.triangles-menu a {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}


.triangles-menu a:first-of-type { 
  padding-top: 1em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.triangles-menu a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.testingPhase {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 6em;
}

/* Table */
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: How do I put in codes? Apparently, its too long.

Comment: @ILoveCSS done!

Comment: You need to add the CSS to the question. You link the CSS in your html with a relative link. I don't have access to the CSS selectors being applied from that file.

Comment: Why is the div with class container wrapped in a html tag? Also, could you post an image of the result you wish to achieve? It's unclear from your description.

Comment: I was trying to make it two different entity earlier on, but apparently it didn't work. @ovokuro

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see any difference between the image of the issue and the perfect solution, apart from the background colours. And yes, you'll need to validate your source. Not just the stray <html> tags, but also things like `"#/about.html"` for URLs, <b> in used in a deprecated manner etc.

Comment: @ILoveCSS I have added it in!

Answer (score 0):

I edited and provided your HTML and CSS code here.

Look at that and see if it's what you want or not?

```css
div.container {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 1%;
  overflow: auto;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 600px;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.footer {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  line-height: 1em;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: blink;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: blink;
}
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 80%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* you can but your code all in one line like above */

#page {
  margin: 20px;
}
/* or on different lines like below */

#logo {
  width: 35%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* but try and be as consist possible */

#nav {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
#nav ul {} #nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 62px;
}
#nav ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #000000;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff8000;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #666;
}
#nav ul li a:active {
  background-color: #ff8f00;
}
#nav ul li.red a {
  background-color: red;
}
#nav ul li.orange a {
  background-color: orange;
}
#nav ul li.blue a {
  background-color: #0080ff;
}
#content {
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
#footer {
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#footer p {
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: grey;
}
/* multiple styles seperated by a , */

#content,
ul li a {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
}
/* User Login Page */

.point-top,
.point-bottom {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
}
.point-top {
  border-bottom: 50px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
.point-bottom {
  border-top: 50px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.triangles-menu {
  background-color: #d5d2d5;
  width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.triangles-menu a {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.triangles-menu a:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 1em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.triangles-menu a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.testingPhase {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1><a href="#"><b>Firewall Rule Review System</b></a></h1>
    <h2><b>Welcome ...</b></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="red"><a href="#"><b>About</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#"><b>Contact</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="blue"><a href="#"><b>Logout</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="point-top"></div>

  <div class="triangles-menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#" name="uploadfile"> Upload File</a>
    <a href="#">File Records</a>
    <a href="#">Change Password</a>
  </div>


  <div class="point-bottom"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="t01">
      <tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Upload-DateTime</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- End Page Content -->
<div class="footer">
  <p>
    Testing
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: actually there is no difference between Image of the issue and Perfect solution. also i can't remember why i suggest you this solution.